# dpkg: warning: old system76-driver package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 134

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, dpkg

My computer lost power and something with apt broke (maybe python related) originally I could not even `sudo apt update` but I got pretty far compared to that but now it fails when trying to install system76-driver, I am stuck.

> things I have already tried, reinstall, uninstall/purge. (same error as below)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

input:

```
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  system76-driver
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/54.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 406541 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../system76-driver_19.10.1~1579103503~18.04~966d6c0~dev_all.deb ...
Fatal Python error: non-string found in code slot

Current thread 0x00007fd5ce9e5740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 487 in _compile_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779 in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/__init__.py", line 2 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32 in <module>
Aborted
dpkg: warning: old system76-driver package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 134
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Fatal Python error: non-string found in code slot

Current thread 0x00007faf80c0b740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 487 in _compile_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779 in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/__init__.py", line 2 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32 in <module>
Aborted
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/system76-driver_19.10.1~1579103503~18.04~966d6c0~dev_all.deb (--unpack):
 new system76-driver package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Fatal Python error: non-string found in code slot

Current thread 0x00007f27ca520740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 487 in _compile_bytecode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779 in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/__init__.py", line 2 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 34 in <module>
Aborted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/system76-driver_19.10.1~1579103503~18.04~966d6c0~dev_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Comment: ```$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was just leftover from the original problem I had already solved (not being able to apt update) and just required me to restart the computer for everything to resolve. For anyone who was curious the original problem was on running apt update I wold get a Fatal Python error: non-string found in code slot and then something that looked like the same errors as above. If I remember correctly since I was working on it for hours the last thing I did before it worked was

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

this allowed update to work but failed on upgrade until a restart.